# Telegram Webhook Not Firing in Group Chats

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I created a bot and set a webhook to a Google Cloud URL.  When addressing my bot 1-on-1, things work properly (event received via webhook, Google Cloud Function processes and responds back into chat via SendMessage API).

However, when the bot joins a group I cannot trigger it by typing `@myBot Message`

Instead, the webhook doesn't even fire off a message.  It just does nothing.

I noticed it *does* respond if I type `/anyrandomtext Message` but of course tries to process the command text as well, so it fails overall.  According to [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots), "Messages that start with a slash are always passed to the bot (along with replies to its messages **and messages that @mention the bot by username**)."

Bot privacy is 'enabled' and so is its ability to join groups.

Comment: Heya, did u succeed in resolving this?

Answer (score -1):

The most likely you haven't set up your bot to be able to read from groups. You have to go to *@BotFather*

```
type '/mybots' -> {choose your bot} -> 'Bot Settings' -> 'Group Privacy' -> 'Turn off'
```

or it can be added to group as admin.

https://core.telegram.org/bots#privacy-mode